# How to use regex on array?

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I would like to find the name `tank2` in the following array, so I do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                           
use strict; use warnings;

my @out = ("aaa\n", "pool: tank2\n", "ccc\n");
foreach my $line (@out) {$line =~ /pool: (.+)/; print $1;}
```

and get

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in print
tank2tank2
```

My two problems are

- For some reason the name is printed twice and with an error.
- How do I save the result/name in a variable when it have been found the first time?

Comment: Instead of `{$line =~ /pool: (.+)/; print $1;}` say `{$line =~ /pool: (.+)/ && print $1;}`

Comment: Never use `$1`, `$2`, and friends unconditionally.

Comment: @GregBacon I think u mean "never use conditionally"

Comment: @Drt Nope. Sandra's code prints the value of `$1` unconditionally, so when the preceding pattern fails to match, it prints anyway, which is the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pretty unreadable version :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                           
use strict; use warnings;

my @out = ("aaa\n", "pool: tank2\n", "ccc\n");
(my $var = (grep{/pool: (.+)/}@out)[0] )=~s/pool: //;
print $var;
```

and your improved version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                           
use strict; use warnings;

my @out = ("aaa\n", "pool: tank2\n", "ccc\n");
for my $line (@out) {
    print $1 if $line =~ /pool: (.+)/; 
}
```

and without `$1`:

```
my $var;
    for my $line (@out){
        print $var if ($var) = ($line =~ /pool: (.+)/);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my @out = ("aaa\n", "pool: tank2\n", "ccc\n");
foreach my $line (@out) {if ($line =~ m/pool: (.+)/) { print $1;}}
```

please notice you will not receive the `\n` in the end, so you will have to print it yourself.